# Saving Amazon Hosted Image Using CURL- 0 Bytes

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to save an image from Amazon on my server, but a 0 byte image is always created. I thought the problem may be no user agent, so I was sure to specify the user agent. Any ideas?

```
$new_thumb = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41g8vo0PgNL._SL160_.jpg';
$img_filename = '/path/to/new/local/image.jpg';

$ch = curl_init(); // Get image
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $new_thumb);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
$picture = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$fh = fopen($img_filename, 'x'); // Save image
fwrite($fh, $picture);
 fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and only changed $img_filename, it worked and I got the image of 3345 bytes.  I suspect a permission problem on your side; does the $img_filename path exist, what are the permissions?

Comment: Yes the path exists and I have the permissions set to 777. The file is being created in the proper directory with the correct name, just 0 bytes.

Comment: maybe a connection problem then?  It must be something with your environment because your code is good.

Comment: What permissions need to be set in php.ini so I can check?

Comment: can you log in with ssh and use wget to try getting the same image from command line?  if you can get it, it's not a connection problem.